# Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$

Tags: continued-fractions

Find the continued fraction of $ \sqrt{67}-4 $ . $$ $$ We Know that if $ N $ is not a perfect square  and if continued fraction of $ \sqrt N $  is $ \sqrt N  =  [a_{1} , \overline {a_{2},a_{3} , \ldots , 2a_{1}} ]$  , then the continued fraction of $ \sqrt N-a_{1}$ is  $ \sqrt N-a_{1}=[\overline {0,a_{2},a_{3},\ldots,a_{n}, 2a_{1}}] $ . But I can't find the continued fraction of $\sqrt {67} $. Please someone help me

Answer (score 10):

The *regular* continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt{67}$ is
$$
8+\frac1{5+}\frac1{2+}\frac1{1+}\frac1{1+}\frac1{7+}\frac1{1+}\frac1{1+}\frac1{2+}\frac1{5+}\frac1{16+}\cdots\>,
$$
and the repeating part is the whole segment between the “$\frac1{5+}$” and the “$\frac1{16+}$”.

You may get it by a repeated process of “derationalizing the denominator”, starting with
$$
\frac{\sqrt{67}-8}1=\frac3{\sqrt{67}+8}=\frac1{\bigl(\sqrt{67}+8\bigr)\big/3}
=\frac1{5+}\frac{\sqrt{67}-7}3\,,\quad\text{etc.}
$$

But here’s an algorithm that mechanizes the whole process, I’m sure it’s well known:
If $N$ is a nonsquare positive integer, put $m=\lfloor \sqrt N\rfloor$, and start with the pair $(p,q)=(m,1)$, then, recursively, put
\begin{align}
q'&=\frac{N-p^2}q\\
d&=\left\lfloor\frac{p+m}{q'}\right\rfloor\\
p'&=dq'-p\quad.
\end{align}
Then the “output” $d$ of this step is the partial denominator that you will see in the continued-fraction expansion. And the process repeats after the first appearance of $d=2m$.

Comment: Prof. Lubin, can you think of a reference for this? I cannot get it to work yet. Note that I have programmed Gauss/Lagrange's method of neighboring reduced forms, as described in Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms. I also don't see how to revise their method to get something of the shape you describe. Dickson's History does not appear to talk about this, at least not in terms i recognize

Comment: The complete cycle of reduced forms equivalent to $x^2 - 67 y^2$ is $\langle  1, 16, -3   \rangle,$
$\langle   -3, 14, 6  \rangle,$
$\langle   6, 10, -7  \rangle,$
$\langle  -7, 4, 9   \rangle,$
$\langle  9, 14, -2   \rangle,$
$\langle  -2, 14, 9   \rangle,$
$\langle  9, 4, -7   \rangle,$
$\langle -7, 10, 6  \rangle,$
$\langle  6, 14, -3   \rangle,$
$\langle -3, 16, 1  \rangle,$
$\langle   1, 16, -3  \rangle.$  including repeating the beginning form

Comment: No reference, @WillJagy, I just analyzed what I do when I calculate the c.f. by repeated derationalization of the denominator. “Cannot get it to work yet” — do you mean that you tried the algorithm above and it gave a different result?

Comment: @Lubin   Question:  does the repeating section always begin at the first term, or can some numbers lead to a sequence  [ a,b,c,d,(repeat_section)] ?

Comment: If you’re taking the square root of a nonsquare integer, @CarlWitthoft , it  always starts at the first term. You’ll get an initial nonperiodic segment if your expression is not integral, I think. In any case, the algorithm works only for $\sqrt n$.

Comment: @Lubin thanks!   Let's see... any finite decimal number can use this algorithm if you first multiply $\sqrt(x)$ by $\frac{1}{\sqrt(10)*10^j}$ .  Now I have to learn how to multiply two continued fractions!

Comment: Have you run this algorithm for some fairly short but nontrivial cases like $\sqrt7$, $\sqrt{11}$, and $\sqrt{13}$ @CarlWitthoft ? Even adding two continued fractions is, I think beyond human capabilities, save by very stupid brute-force methods. For multiplication, unless you’re doing $\sqrt m\sqrt n$, it must be about as impossible. There’s not any obvious relation between $(\sqrt m, \sqrt n)$ and $\sqrt{mn}$ even. Every part of this mathematical world is all very mysterious.

Comment: @Lubin  I went back and realized that $\frac{m}{n} =  \frac{1}{n^2} * (m*n)$  , so any *rational* number's sqrt can be found using your method.

Answer (score 5):

Typeset the hand calculation method Prof. Lubin indicated. I would say that the reason I did not know this was that I had never calculated one of these by hand. There is a lesson in that.

$$  \sqrt { 67} = 8 +     \frac{  \sqrt {67} - 8 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {67} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 8 }{3 } = 5 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 7 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {67} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 7 }{6 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 5 }{6 } $$
$$    \frac{ 6 }{   \sqrt {67} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 5 }{7 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 2 }{7 } $$
$$    \frac{ 7 }{   \sqrt {67} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 2 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 7 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {67} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 7 }{2 } = 7 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 7 }{2 } $$
$$    \frac{ 2 }{   \sqrt {67} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 7 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 2 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {67} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 2 }{7 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 5 }{7 } $$
$$    \frac{ 7 }{   \sqrt {67} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 5 }{6 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 7 }{6 } $$
$$    \frac{ 6 }{   \sqrt {67} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 7 }{3 } = 5 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 8 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {67} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {67} + 8 }{1 } = 16 +  \frac{    \sqrt {67} - 8 }{1 } $$

My favorite tableau for a simple continued fraction:
$$ 
\small
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 8 & & 5 & & 2 & & 1 & & 1 & & 7 & & 1 & & 1 & & 2 & & 5 & & 16 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 41 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 90 }{ 11 }   & &   \frac{ 131 }{ 16 }   & &   \frac{ 221 }{ 27 }   & &   \frac{ 1678 }{ 205 }   & &   \frac{ 1899 }{ 232 }   & &   \frac{ 3577 }{ 437 }   & &   \frac{ 9053 }{ 1106 }   & &   \frac{ 48842 }{ 5967 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -3 & & 6 & & -7 & & 9 & & -2 & & 9 & & -7 & & 6 & & -3 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 67 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  8  \\  
  \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & 8^2 - 67 \cdot 1^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 41 }{ 5 }   & 41^2 - 67 \cdot 5^2 = 6 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 90 }{ 11 }   & 90^2 - 67 \cdot 11^2 = -7 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 131 }{ 16 }   & 131^2 - 67 \cdot 16^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 221 }{ 27 }   & 221^2 - 67 \cdot 27^2 = -2 &     \mbox{digit}  &  7  \\  
  \frac{ 1678 }{ 205 }   & 1678^2 - 67 \cdot 205^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1899 }{ 232 }   & 1899^2 - 67 \cdot 232^2 = -7 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 3577 }{ 437 }   & 3577^2 - 67 \cdot 437^2 = 6 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 9053 }{ 1106 }   & 9053^2 - 67 \cdot 1106^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 48842 }{ 5967 }   & 48842^2 - 67 \cdot 5967^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  16  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

I also did 73 which seems to be the only example in Perron(1913)
$$  \sqrt { 73} = 8 +     \frac{  \sqrt {73} - 8 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {73} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {73} + 8 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {73} - 1 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {73} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {73} + 1 }{8 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {73} - 7 }{8 } $$
$$    \frac{ 8 }{   \sqrt {73} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {73} + 7 }{3 } = 5 +  \frac{    \sqrt {73} - 8 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {73} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {73} + 8 }{3 } = 5 +  \frac{    \sqrt {73} - 7 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {73} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {73} + 7 }{8 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {73} - 1 }{8 } $$
$$    \frac{ 8 }{   \sqrt {73} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {73} + 1 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {73} - 8 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {73} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {73} + 8 }{1 } = 16 +  \frac{    \sqrt {73} - 8 }{1 } $$

Tableau:
$$ 
\tiny
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 8 & & 1 & & 1 & & 5 & & 5 & & 1 & & 1 & & 16 & & 1 & & 1 & & 5 & & 5 & & 1 & & 1 & & 16 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 17 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 94 }{ 11 }   & &   \frac{ 487 }{ 57 }   & &   \frac{ 581 }{ 68 }   & &   \frac{ 1068 }{ 125 }   & &   \frac{ 17669 }{ 2068 }   & &   \frac{ 18737 }{ 2193 }   & &   \frac{ 36406 }{ 4261 }   & &   \frac{ 200767 }{ 23498 }   & &   \frac{ 1040241 }{ 121751 }   & &   \frac{ 1241008 }{ 145249 }   & &   \frac{ 2281249 }{ 267000 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -9 & & 8 & & -3 & & 3 & & -8 & & 9 & & -1 & & 9 & & -8 & & 3 & & -3 & & 8 & & -9 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 73 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  8  \\  
  \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & 8^2 - 73 \cdot 1^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 9 }{ 1 }   & 9^2 - 73 \cdot 1^2 = 8 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 17 }{ 2 }   & 17^2 - 73 \cdot 2^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 94 }{ 11 }   & 94^2 - 73 \cdot 11^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 487 }{ 57 }   & 487^2 - 73 \cdot 57^2 = -8 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 581 }{ 68 }   & 581^2 - 73 \cdot 68^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1068 }{ 125 }   & 1068^2 - 73 \cdot 125^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  16  \\  
  \frac{ 17669 }{ 2068 }   & 17669^2 - 73 \cdot 2068^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 18737 }{ 2193 }   & 18737^2 - 73 \cdot 2193^2 = -8 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 36406 }{ 4261 }   & 36406^2 - 73 \cdot 4261^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 200767 }{ 23498 }   & 200767^2 - 73 \cdot 23498^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 1040241 }{ 121751 }   & 1040241^2 - 73 \cdot 121751^2 = 8 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1241008 }{ 145249 }   & 1241008^2 - 73 \cdot 145249^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 2281249 }{ 267000 }   & 2281249^2 - 73 \cdot 267000^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  16  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

Note how we need to go twice through the "digits" to get to $1,$ as
$$      1068^2 - 73 \cdot 125^2 = -1    $$
See how Perron (1913) displays the beginning of the calculation for $\sqrt {73}$
[image]
Perron does (on just one page) show the diagram I have been calling a tableau. He calls it a Schema:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Once upon a time, I taught a course for high-school teachers in which this stuff was a segment. I (thought I) demonstrated that for $\sqrt n$, the pattern is symmetric, as well as the proposition that all the partial denominators but the last are $\le n$, and when this does occur it’s the middle of the pattern. Tried recently to reconstruct my proofs for these last statements, and hit a snag.

Comment: i appreciate you

Comment: I notice that five years ago I could not reconstruct my argument for the symmetry of the pattern by using “my” algorithm. More recently, I got an argument for that.

Comment: @Lubin  I see, in 2017 you said you did not have the proofs you used for the high-school teachers. Have you posted those anywhere?

Comment: No, @WillJagy, that was when I was teaching at Bowdoin, 1962-66, long before electrons were discovered.