# Why are the minimal solutions of the Pell equation $x^2-(n^2-3)y^2=1$ larger than average when $3 \not | n$?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

[Here](https://hastebin.com/bipoduqeja)'s a list of the $x$ in the fundamental solution of $x^2-dy^2=1$. It seems when $d=n^2-3$ for an integer $n$ the $x$ is often quite large. Is this a coincidence or is there an explanation?

For $n>5$ the continued fraction of $\sqrt {n^2-3}$ starts with
$$\sqrt {n^2-3} = \left[n-1;1,n-2-\lfloor n/3\rfloor, a_n...\right]$$
Where $a_n=3$ if $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $1$ otherwise. Maybe this is related.

When $n$ is a multiple of 3, the solution is small because $(6n^2-1)^2-(9n^2-3)(2n)^2=1$.

In [this](http://paste.debian.net/988753/) file the $n$th line is the continued fraction of $\sqrt{(3n+1)^2-3}$. There are some interesting patterns in it, for example in the 12th column there seems to be a pattern repeating mod 9: $13,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,5$. [Here](http://paste.debian.net/988760/)'s the same thing for $\sqrt{(3n+2)^2-3}$.

[image: 4]
[image: 5]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]

Here the blue line is the log of the geometric average of the x in the minimal solution of the pell equation and the orange line is that only for numbers of the form $n^2-3$. Eyeballing that last plot
$$\ln\left(\left(x_1x_6x_{13}\dots x_{9998241}\right)^{1/3162}\right)\approx\ln\left(\left(x_1x_2x_3\dots x_{10^7}\right)^{10^{-7}}\right) + 150$$
$$(x_1x_6x_{13}\dots x_{9998241})^{1/3162}\approx e^{150}(x_1x_2x_3\dots x_{10^7})^{10^{-7}}$$
Where $(x_n, y_n)$ is the fundamental solution of $x^2-ny^2=1$, when $n$ is a square I set $x_n=1$. Also, the geometric average of the subsequence is higher than the average of the whole sequence for all $61\leq n < 10^7$.

Exluding the cases where n is a multiple of 3 makes the effect even larger:
[image: 8]

Comment: Probably a coincidence. For $n=149$, we have a quite large fundamental solution and $149$ has not this form. But the recordholders (larger $x$-value in the fundamental solution than for every smaller $n$) seem to be almost always prime numbers.

Comment: The only composite numbers I found for the recordholders are $10$ and $46$

Comment: The fundamental solution for $n=141=12^2-3$ is, on the other hand, rather small.

Comment: The larger ones will be cases where there is a solution to negative Pell, $u^2 - D v^2 = -1.$ The fundamental solution for $+1$ is then large, being $x = u^2 + D v^2, y = 2 u v$

Comment: @Peter when $n$ is a multiple of 3 the fundamental solution is small. I wrote an explanation in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

Here is $$ D = 8^2 - 3 = 61. $$

$$  \sqrt { 61} = 7 +     \frac{  \sqrt {61} - 7 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{12 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{12 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 12 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{3 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{4 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 4 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {61} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 4 }{5 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 6 }{5 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {61} - 6 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 6 }{5 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 4 }{5 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {61} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 4 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{4 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{3 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 5 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {61} - 5 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 5 }{12 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{12 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 12 }{   \sqrt {61} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {61} + 7 }{1 } = 14 +  \frac{    \sqrt {61} - 7 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 7 & & 1 & & 4 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 4 & & 1 & & 14 & & 1 & & 4 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 4 & & 1 & & 14 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 39 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 125 }{ 16 }   & &   \frac{ 164 }{ 21 }   & &   \frac{ 453 }{ 58 }   & &   \frac{ 1070 }{ 137 }   & &   \frac{ 1523 }{ 195 }   & &   \frac{ 5639 }{ 722 }   & &   \frac{ 24079 }{ 3083 }   & &   \frac{ 29718 }{ 3805 }   & &   \frac{ 440131 }{ 56353 }   & &   \frac{ 469849 }{ 60158 }   & &   \frac{ 2319527 }{ 296985 }   & &   \frac{ 7428430 }{ 951113 }   & &   \frac{ 9747957 }{ 1248098 }   & &   \frac{ 26924344 }{ 3447309 }   & &   \frac{ 63596645 }{ 8142716 }   & &   \frac{ 90520989 }{ 11590025 }   & &   \frac{ 335159612 }{ 42912791 }   & &   \frac{ 1431159437 }{ 183241189 }   & &   \frac{ 1766319049 }{ 226153980 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -12 & & 3 & & -4 & & 9 & & -5 & & 5 & & -9 & & 4 & & -3 & & 12 & & -1 & & 12 & & -3 & & 4 & & -9 & & 5 & & -5 & & 9 & & -4 & & 3 & & -12 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ \tiny 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 7 & & 1 & & 4 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 4 & & 1 & & 14 & & 1 & & 4 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 4 & & 1 & & 14 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 39 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 125 }{ 16 }   & &   \frac{ 164 }{ 21 }   & &   \frac{ 453 }{ 58 }   & &   \frac{ 1070 }{ 137 }   & &   \frac{ 1523 }{ 195 }   & &   \frac{ 5639 }{ 722 }   & &   \frac{ 24079 }{ 3083 }   & &   \frac{ 29718 }{ 3805 }   & &   \frac{ 440131 }{ 56353 }   & &   \frac{ 469849 }{ 60158 }   & &   \frac{ 2319527 }{ 296985 }   & &   \frac{ 7428430 }{ 951113 }   & &   \frac{ 9747957 }{ 1248098 }   & &   \frac{ 26924344 }{ 3447309 }   & &   \frac{ 63596645 }{ 8142716 }   & &   \frac{ 90520989 }{ 11590025 }   & &   \frac{ 335159612 }{ 42912791 }   & &   \frac{ 1431159437 }{ 183241189 }   & &   \frac{ 1766319049 }{ 226153980 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -12 & & 3 & & -4 & & 9 & & -5 & & 5 & & -9 & & 4 & & -3 & & 12 & & -1 & & 12 & & -3 & & 4 & & -9 & & 5 & & -5 & & 9 & & -4 & & 3 & & -12 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 61 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  7  \\  
  \frac{ 7 }{ 1 }   & 7^2 - 61 \cdot 1^2 = -12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 8 }{ 1 }   & 8^2 - 61 \cdot 1^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 39 }{ 5 }   & 39^2 - 61 \cdot 5^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 125 }{ 16 }   & 125^2 - 61 \cdot 16^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 164 }{ 21 }   & 164^2 - 61 \cdot 21^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 453 }{ 58 }   & 453^2 - 61 \cdot 58^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 1070 }{ 137 }   & 1070^2 - 61 \cdot 137^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1523 }{ 195 }   & 1523^2 - 61 \cdot 195^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 5639 }{ 722 }   & 5639^2 - 61 \cdot 722^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 24079 }{ 3083 }   & 24079^2 - 61 \cdot 3083^2 = 12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 29718 }{ 3805 }   & 29718^2 - 61 \cdot 3805^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
  \frac{ 440131 }{ 56353 }   & 440131^2 - 61 \cdot 56353^2 = 12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 469849 }{ 60158 }   & 469849^2 - 61 \cdot 60158^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 2319527 }{ 296985 }   & 2319527^2 - 61 \cdot 296985^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 7428430 }{ 951113 }   & 7428430^2 - 61 \cdot 951113^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 9747957 }{ 1248098 }   & 9747957^2 - 61 \cdot 1248098^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 26924344 }{ 3447309 }   & 26924344^2 - 61 \cdot 3447309^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 63596645 }{ 8142716 }   & 63596645^2 - 61 \cdot 8142716^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 90520989 }{ 11590025 }   & 90520989^2 - 61 \cdot 11590025^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 335159612 }{ 42912791 }   & 335159612^2 - 61 \cdot 42912791^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 1431159437 }{ 183241189 }   & 1431159437^2 - 61 \cdot 183241189^2 = -12 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1766319049 }{ 226153980 }   & 1766319049^2 - 61 \cdot 226153980^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$