# Quadratic Diophantine equation - Find all integer solutions

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I have a Quadratic  Diophantine equation.

I am sorry I didn't get how to show correctly. So I used a
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnc3V.png)

How can I find all integer solutions? Should I do something with Z(14)?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html

Answer (score 1):

The integer equation $11 x^2 - 14 y^2 = 1$ is impossible. However, I do not see that a proof is available for a beginner. There is no simple proof with congruences. There is one using, in effect, continued fractions.

The principal genus of this discriminant is two forms,
$$ x^2 - 154 y^2 $$
$$ 2 x^2 - 77 y^2,  $$
and your form $11x^2 - 14 y^2$ is $SL_2 \mathbb Z$ equivalent to $2x^2 - 77 y^2$ and simply does not integrally represent $1.$

The other genus is their negatives,
 $$ -x^2 + 154 y^2 $$
$$ -2 x^2 + 77 y^2,  $$

Here are a list of the class group, Gauss-Lagrange reduced forms, and the Lagrange cycle of your form

```
    1.             1          24         -10   cycle length            10
    2.            -1          24          10   cycle length            10
    3.             2          24          -5   cycle length             8
    4.            -2          24           5   cycle length             8

  form class number is   4

jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$ ./indefCycle 11 0 -14

  0  form             11           0         -14  delta      0
  1  form            -14           0          11  delta      1
  2  form             11          22          -3


          -1          -1
           0          -1

To Return  
          -1           1
           0          -1

0  form   11 22 -3   delta  -7     ambiguous  
1  form   -3 20 18   delta  1
2  form   18 16 -5   delta  -4
3  form   -5 24 2   delta  12
4  form   2 24 -5   delta  -4     ambiguous  
5  form   -5 16 18   delta  1
6  form   18 20 -3   delta  -7
7  form   -3 22 11   delta  2
8  form   11 22 -3


  form   11 x^2  + 22 x y  -3 y^2 

minimum was   2rep   x = 5   y = 39 disc 616 dSqrt 24  M_Ratio  4.760331
Automorph, written on right of Gram matrix:  
2419  5148
18876  40171
=========================================
jagy@phobeusjunior:~/old drive/home/jagy/Cplusplus$
```

Answer (score 0):

Second answer: your problem is equivalent to showing, with integers $x,y,$ that
$$  x^2 - 154 y^2 \neq 2   $$
This may be more familiar, it is a matter of constructing the continued fraction for $\sqrt {154}$ and showing that, for any "convergent" $\frac{p}{q},$ we always have $p^2 - 154 q^2 \neq 2.$

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 154} = 12 +     \frac{  \sqrt {154} - 12 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {154} - 12 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 12 }{10 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 8 }{10 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 10 }{   \sqrt {154} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 8 }{9 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 10 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {154} - 10 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 10 }{6 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 8 }{6 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 6 }{   \sqrt {154} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 8 }{15 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 7 }{15 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 15 }{   \sqrt {154} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 7 }{7 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 7 }{7 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 7 }{   \sqrt {154} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 7 }{15 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 8 }{15 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 15 }{   \sqrt {154} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 8 }{6 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 10 }{6 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 6 }{   \sqrt {154} - 10 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 10 }{9 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 8 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {154} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 8 }{10 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 12 }{10 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 10 }{   \sqrt {154} - 12 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {154} + 12 }{1 } = 24 +  \frac{    \sqrt {154} - 12 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 12 & & 2 & & 2 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 2 & & 2 & & 24 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 12 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 25 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 62 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 211 }{ 17 }   & &   \frac{ 273 }{ 22 }   & &   \frac{ 757 }{ 61 }   & &   \frac{ 1030 }{ 83 }   & &   \frac{ 3847 }{ 310 }   & &   \frac{ 8724 }{ 703 }   & &   \frac{ 21295 }{ 1716 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -10 & & 9 & & -6 & & 15 & & -7 & & 15 & & -6 & & 9 & & -10 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 154 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  12  \\  
  \frac{ 12 }{ 1 }   & 12^2 - 154 \cdot 1^2 = -10 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 25 }{ 2 }   & 25^2 - 154 \cdot 2^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 62 }{ 5 }   & 62^2 - 154 \cdot 5^2 = -6 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 211 }{ 17 }   & 211^2 - 154 \cdot 17^2 = 15 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 273 }{ 22 }   & 273^2 - 154 \cdot 22^2 = -7 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 757 }{ 61 }   & 757^2 - 154 \cdot 61^2 = 15 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1030 }{ 83 }   & 1030^2 - 154 \cdot 83^2 = -6 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 3847 }{ 310 }   & 3847^2 - 154 \cdot 310^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 8724 }{ 703 }   & 8724^2 - 154 \cdot 703^2 = -10 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 21295 }{ 1716 }   & 21295^2 - 154 \cdot 1716^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  24  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking for $(x, y)$ pairs that solve the equation: $$11x^2-14y^2=1$$ you can use the on solver at [here](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/aa.html) to show that there are no solutions in integers.