# Pell's equation with d congruent to 1 mod 4

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Currently in class we have seen a method for solving Pell's equation:

$$x^2 - dy^2 = 1$$

Using the facts: $$N_{K}(\alpha) = \pm1 \iff \alpha \in O_K^{X} \iff \alpha = \pm u^r $$

Where $u$ is the fundamental unit.
However, I'm rather stumped as to how to proceed in solving the Pell's equation:
$$x^2 - 13y^2 = -1$$

Because $d \equiv 1 \mod{4} $, so the ring of integers will take the form $\mathbb{Z}[\dfrac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2}]$ and so I can't view the equation as the norm of some unit in the ring of integers.

Is there a systematic way to proceed using these results or am I to explore different avenues? We haven't covered anything else beyond these results in relation to Pell's equation.

Comment: $18^2-13 \times 5^2 = -1$

Answer (score 1):

THEOREM 1: With prime $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ there is always a solution to $$ x^2 - p y^2 = -1  $$ in integers. The proof is from Mordell, Diophantine Equations, pages 55-56.

PROOF: Take the smallest integer pair $T>1,U >0$ such that $$ T^2 - p U^2 = 1. $$
We know that $T$ is odd and $U$ is even. So, we have the integer equation
$$ \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right)  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = p  \left( \frac{U}{2} \right)^2. $$

We have $$ \gcd \left( \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right),  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) \right) = 1. $$
Indeed, 
$$  \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) -   \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = 1. $$

There are now two cases, by unique factorization in integers:

$$ \mbox{(A):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = p a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = b^2 $$

$$  \mbox{(B):}  \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) =  a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = p b^2 $$

Now, in case (B), we find that $(a,b)$ are smaller than $(T,U),$ but $T \geq 3, a > 1,$ and $a^2 - p b^2 = 1.$ This is a contradiction, as our hypothesis is that $(T,U)$ is minimal.

As a result, case (A) holds, with evident $$p a^2 - b^2 = \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) - \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = 1, $$
so
$$  b^2 - p a^2 = -1.   $$
$$ $$
$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

THEOREM 2: With primes $p \neq q,$ with $p \equiv q \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and Legendre $(p|q)=(q|p) = -1,$ there is always a solution to $$ x^2 - pq y^2 = -1  $$ in integers. The proof is from Mordell, Diophantine Equations, pages 55-56.

PROOF: Take the smallest integer pair $T>1,U >0$ such that $$ T^2 - pq U^2 = 1. $$
We know that $T$ is odd and $U$ is even. So, we have the integer equation
$$ \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right)  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = pq  \left( \frac{U}{2} \right)^2. $$

We have $$ \gcd \left( \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right),  \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) \right) = 1. $$

There are now four cases, by unique factorization in integers:

$$  \mbox{(1):}  \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) =  a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = pq b^2 $$

$$ \mbox{(2):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = p a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = q b^2 $$
$$ \mbox{(3):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = q a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = p b^2 $$
$$ \mbox{(4):} \; \; \; \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) = pq a^2, \; \; \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) =  b^2 $$

Now, in case (1), we find that $(a,b)$ are smaller than $(T,U),$ but $T \geq 3, a > 1,$ and $a^2 - pq b^2 = 1.$ This is a contradiction, as our hypothesis is that $(T,U)$ is minimal.

In case $(2),$ we have
$$  p a^2 - q b^2 = 1.  $$
$$  p a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod q,    $$ so $a$ is nonzero mod $q,$ then
$$ p \equiv \left( \frac{1}{a} \right)^2 \pmod q.  $$
This contradicts  the hypothesis $(p|q) = -1.$

In case $(3),$ we have
$$  q a^2 - p b^2 = 1.  $$
$$  q a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p,    $$ so $a$ is nonzero mod $p,$ then
$$ q \equiv \left( \frac{1}{a} \right)^2 \pmod p.  $$
This contradicts  the hypothesis $(q|p) = -1.$

As a result, case (4) holds, with evident $$pq a^2 - b^2 = \left( \frac{T+1}{2} \right) - \left( \frac{T-1}{2} \right) = 1, $$
so
$$  b^2 - pq a^2 = -1.   $$
$$ $$
$$ \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  $$

The viewpoint of real quadratic fields an norms of fundamental units is more concerned with $x^2 + xy - k y^2,$ where $4k+1 = pq$ in the second theorem. However, we showed above that the existence of a solution to $u^2 - (4k+1)v^2 = -1$ gives an immediate construction for a solution to  $x^2 + xy - k y^2=-1,$ namely $x=u-v, y=2v.$

David Speyer reminded me of something Kap wrote out for me, years and years ago. From David's comments, I now understand what Kap was trying to show me. If $x^2 + x y - 2 k y^2 = -1,$ then $(2x+y)^2 - (8k+1)y^2 = -4. $ This is impossible $\pmod 8$ unless $y$ is even, in which case $(x + \frac{y}{2})^2 - (8k+1) \left( \frac{y}{2}\right)^2 = -1.$

There is more to it when we have $x^2 + x y - k y^2 = -1$ with odd $k.$ I wrote Kap's note in Buell, page 31.  Take
$$ u =  \frac{ 2 x^3 +3 x^2 y + (6k+3)x y^2 + (3k+1)y^3}{2},  $$
$$ v = \frac{3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2 + (k+1)y^3}{2}.              $$
$$ u^2 - (4k+1) v^2 = -1,    $$ since
$$ u^2 - (4k+1) v^2 = \left( x^2 + x y - k y^2 \right)^3.    $$

...

Answer (score 0):

If $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is a (positive) prime, there is always an integer solution to $x^2 - p y^2 = -1.$ The short proof is in Mordell, Diophantine Equations.  The same proof gives the same conclusion for primes $p\equiv q \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$ Legendre symbol $(p|q) = -1,$ and $x^2 - pq y^2 = -1.$ I have probably posted both proofs on this site. There is no guarantee if $(p|q) = 1.$ The two smallest such failures are $x^2 - 205 y^2 \neq -1$ and $x^2 - 221 y^2 \neq -1.$

Actually finding such answers is simply finding the continued fraction for the square root of the $p$ or $pq$

===================================================================

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 13} = 3 +     \frac{  \sqrt {13} - 3 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {13} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 3 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 1 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {13} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 1 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 2 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {13} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 2 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 1 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {13} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 1 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 3 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {13} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 3 }{1 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 3 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 119 }{ 33 }   & &   \frac{ 137 }{ 38 }   & &   \frac{ 256 }{ 71 }   & &   \frac{ 393 }{ 109 }   & &   \frac{ 649 }{ 180 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -4 & & 3 & & -3 & & 4 & & -1 & & 4 & & -3 & & 3 & & -4 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 13 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & 3^2 - 13 \cdot 1^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & 4^2 - 13 \cdot 1^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }   & 7^2 - 13 \cdot 2^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }   & 11^2 - 13 \cdot 3^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }   & 18^2 - 13 \cdot 5^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 119 }{ 33 }   & 119^2 - 13 \cdot 33^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 137 }{ 38 }   & 137^2 - 13 \cdot 38^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 256 }{ 71 }   & 256^2 - 13 \cdot 71^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 393 }{ 109 }   & 393^2 - 13 \cdot 109^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 649 }{ 180 }   & 649^2 - 13 \cdot 180^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

=======================================

$$  \sqrt { 85} = 9 +     \frac{  \sqrt {85} - 9 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {85} - 9 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {85} + 9 }{4 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {85} - 7 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {85} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {85} + 7 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {85} - 2 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {85} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {85} + 2 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {85} - 7 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {85} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {85} + 7 }{4 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {85} - 9 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {85} - 9 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {85} + 9 }{1 } = 18 +  \frac{    \sqrt {85} - 9 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 9 & & 4 & & 1 & & 1 & & 4 & & 18 & & 4 & & 1 & & 1 & & 4 & & 18 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 37 }{ 4 }   & &   \frac{ 46 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 83 }{ 9 }   & &   \frac{ 378 }{ 41 }   & &   \frac{ 6887 }{ 747 }   & &   \frac{ 27926 }{ 3029 }   & &   \frac{ 34813 }{ 3776 }   & &   \frac{ 62739 }{ 6805 }   & &   \frac{ 285769 }{ 30996 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -4 & & 9 & & -9 & & 4 & & -1 & & 4 & & -9 & & 9 & & -4 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 85 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  9  \\  
  \frac{ 9 }{ 1 }   & 9^2 - 85 \cdot 1^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 37 }{ 4 }   & 37^2 - 85 \cdot 4^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 46 }{ 5 }   & 46^2 - 85 \cdot 5^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 83 }{ 9 }   & 83^2 - 85 \cdot 9^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 378 }{ 41 }   & 378^2 - 85 \cdot 41^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  18  \\  
  \frac{ 6887 }{ 747 }   & 6887^2 - 85 \cdot 747^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 27926 }{ 3029 }   & 27926^2 - 85 \cdot 3029^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 34813 }{ 3776 }   & 34813^2 - 85 \cdot 3776^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 62739 }{ 6805 }   & 62739^2 - 85 \cdot 6805^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 285769 }{ 30996 }   & 285769^2 - 85 \cdot 30996^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  18  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

=================================================================

$$  \sqrt { 205} = 14 +     \frac{  \sqrt {205} - 14 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {205} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 14 }{9 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 13 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {205} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 13 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 11 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {205} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 11 }{21 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 10 }{21 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 21 }{   \sqrt {205} - 10 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 10 }{5 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 10 }{5 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {205} - 10 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 10 }{21 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 11 }{21 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 21 }{   \sqrt {205} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 11 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 13 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {205} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 13 }{9 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 14 }{9 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {205} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {205} + 14 }{1 } = 28 +  \frac{    \sqrt {205} - 14 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 14 & & 3 & & 6 & & 1 & & 4 & & 1 & & 6 & & 3 & & 28 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 43 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 272 }{ 19 }   & &   \frac{ 315 }{ 22 }   & &   \frac{ 1532 }{ 107 }   & &   \frac{ 1847 }{ 129 }   & &   \frac{ 12614 }{ 881 }   & &   \frac{ 39689 }{ 2772 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -9 & & 4 & & -21 & & 5 & & -21 & & 4 & & -9 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 205 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
  \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & 14^2 - 205 \cdot 1^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 43 }{ 3 }   & 43^2 - 205 \cdot 3^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 272 }{ 19 }   & 272^2 - 205 \cdot 19^2 = -21 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 315 }{ 22 }   & 315^2 - 205 \cdot 22^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 1532 }{ 107 }   & 1532^2 - 205 \cdot 107^2 = -21 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1847 }{ 129 }   & 1847^2 - 205 \cdot 129^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 12614 }{ 881 }   & 12614^2 - 205 \cdot 881^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 39689 }{ 2772 }   & 39689^2 - 205 \cdot 2772^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  28  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

=====================================================================

$$  \sqrt { 221} = 14 +     \frac{  \sqrt {221} - 14 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {221} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 14 }{25 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 11 }{25 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 25 }{   \sqrt {221} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 11 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 13 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {221} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 13 }{13 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 13 }{13 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 13 }{   \sqrt {221} - 13 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 13 }{4 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 11 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {221} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 11 }{25 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 14 }{25 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 25 }{   \sqrt {221} - 14 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {221} + 14 }{1 } = 28 +  \frac{    \sqrt {221} - 14 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 14 & & 1 & & 6 & & 2 & & 6 & & 1 & & 28 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 15 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 104 }{ 7 }   & &   \frac{ 223 }{ 15 }   & &   \frac{ 1442 }{ 97 }   & &   \frac{ 1665 }{ 112 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -25 & & 4 & & -13 & & 4 & & -25 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 221 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  14  \\  
  \frac{ 14 }{ 1 }   & 14^2 - 221 \cdot 1^2 = -25 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 15 }{ 1 }   & 15^2 - 221 \cdot 1^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 104 }{ 7 }   & 104^2 - 221 \cdot 7^2 = -13 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 223 }{ 15 }   & 223^2 - 221 \cdot 15^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 1442 }{ 97 }   & 1442^2 - 221 \cdot 97^2 = -25 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1665 }{ 112 }   & 1665^2 - 221 \cdot 112^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  28  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

==============================================================