# Diophantine equation $dx^2-y^2=d-1$ for non-square $d$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

For $d=2$ or $3$ the continuous fractions for $\sqrt 2$ and $\sqrt 3$ help (at least partially), but for $d\ge 5$, this doesn't seem to work.

Is there any known solution or technique to solve this equation?

Comment: you start with the known $(1,1)$ solution and produce others with solutions from $u^2 - d v^2 = 1.$ These might be all solutions, depends on $d$

Comment: It seems the equations are in the form of generalized Pell equations, with methods to solve them provided in several places online, such as at [Solving the generalized Pell equation](https://thilinaatsympy.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/solving-the-generalized-pell-equation/).

Answer (score 0):

here is a good one, several orbits, your $d=13.$
There are six orbits, with $w_n^2 - 13 v_n^2 = -12,$ and recurrences
$$ w_{n+12} = 1298 w_{n+6} - w_n \; , \; $$
$$ v_{n+12} = 1298 v_{n+6} - v_n \; . \; $$

The orbit we knew about begins with $w$ in
$$ 1, 2989, 3879721, 5035874869, $$ and $v$ in
$$ 1, 829, 1076041,  1396700389,   $$

The next (out of six) orbit begins
$$ 14, 18446,  23942894, $$ 
$$  4, 5116, 6640564,  $$

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    649   2340
    180   649
  Automorphism backwards:  
    649   -2340
    -180   649

  649^2 - 13 180^2 = 1

 w^2 - 13 v^2 = -12 =   -1 * 2^2 3

Thu May  9 12:08:38 PDT 2019

w:  1  v:  1  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  14  v:  4  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  25  v:  7  SEED   KEEP +- 
w:  155  v:  43  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -25 ,  7
w:  274  v:  76  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -14 ,  4
w:  1691  v:  469  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  -1 ,  1

w:  2989  v:  829
w:  18446  v:  5116
w:  32605  v:  9043
w:  201215  v:  55807
w:  355666  v:  98644
w:  2194919  v:  608761

w:  3879721  v:  1076041
w:  23942894  v:  6640564

Thu May  9 12:08:53 PDT 2019

 w^2 - 13 v^2 = -12 =   -1 * 2^2 3
```

well, there are several details.

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Lubin_tableaux  13
```

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 13} = 3 +     \frac{  \sqrt {13} - 3 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {13} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 3 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 1 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {13} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 1 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 2 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {13} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 2 }{3 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 1 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {13} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 1 }{4 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 3 }{4 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 4 }{   \sqrt {13} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {13} + 3 }{1 } = 6 +  \frac{    \sqrt {13} - 3 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 3 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 1 & & 6 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 119 }{ 33 }   & &   \frac{ 137 }{ 38 }   & &   \frac{ 256 }{ 71 }   & &   \frac{ 393 }{ 109 }   & &   \frac{ 649 }{ 180 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -4 & & 3 & & -3 & & 4 & & -1 & & 4 & & -3 & & 3 & & -4 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 13 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 3 }{ 1 }   & 3^2 - 13 \cdot 1^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & 4^2 - 13 \cdot 1^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 7 }{ 2 }   & 7^2 - 13 \cdot 2^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 11 }{ 3 }   & 11^2 - 13 \cdot 3^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 18 }{ 5 }   & 18^2 - 13 \cdot 5^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 119 }{ 33 }   & 119^2 - 13 \cdot 33^2 = 4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 137 }{ 38 }   & 137^2 - 13 \cdot 38^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 256 }{ 71 }   & 256^2 - 13 \cdot 71^2 = 3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 393 }{ 109 }   & 393^2 - 13 \cdot 109^2 = -4 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 649 }{ 180 }   & 649^2 - 13 \cdot 180^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$