# Showing that this ideal is non-principal

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

The problem I am given is to find the ideal class group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$, and only have remaining the issue of showing that $P = (2,\sqrt{19}+1)$ (or equivalently $Q_{\pm} = (3,\sqrt{19} \pm 1)$) is non-principal. The method I usually employ in this situation is to consider integer solutions to the equation $a^2-19b^2 = \pm 2$, and then, by taking this equation modulo some number, trying to obtain a contradiction. Although I can remove the $+2$ case by observing that $2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo 19, I cannot find a way to contradict the $-2$ case.

Also, are there any other more effective general methods for determining non-principality of prime ideals, especially those of rings of integers of real quadratic fields, I am seeming to run into similar issues quite often.

Comment: $6^2-19=17=-2 $ mod 19

Answer (score 3):

$$  13^2 - 19 \cdot 3^2 = -2                       $$

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 19} = 4 +     \frac{  \sqrt {19} - 4 }{ 1 }  $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {19} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {19} + 4 }{3 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {19} - 2 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {19} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {19} + 2 }{5 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {19} - 3 }{5 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {19} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {19} + 3 }{2 } = 3 +  \frac{    \sqrt {19} - 3 }{2 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 2 }{   \sqrt {19} - 3 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {19} + 3 }{5 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {19} - 2 }{5 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {19} - 2 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {19} + 2 }{3 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {19} - 4 }{3 } $$ 
 $$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {19} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {19} + 4 }{1 } = 8 +  \frac{    \sqrt {19} - 4 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
 $$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 4 & & 2 & & 1 & & 3 & & 1 & & 2 & & 8 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 3 }   & &   \frac{ 48 }{ 11 }   & &   \frac{ 61 }{ 14 }   & &   \frac{ 170 }{ 39 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -3 & & 5 & & -2 & & 5 & & -3 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 19 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 4 }{ 1 }   & 4^2 - 19 \cdot 1^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 9 }{ 2 }   & 9^2 - 19 \cdot 2^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 13 }{ 3 }   & 13^2 - 19 \cdot 3^2 = -2 &     \mbox{digit}  &  3  \\  
  \frac{ 48 }{ 11 }   & 48^2 - 19 \cdot 11^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 61 }{ 14 }   & 61^2 - 19 \cdot 14^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 170 }{ 39 }   & 170^2 - 19 \cdot 39^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  8  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

.......................

Comment: Ah my mistake, thank you

Comment: So, with a little help from Wolfram Alpha, it looks like $\langle 2, \sqrt{19} + 1 \rangle = \langle 13 + 3 \sqrt{19} \rangle$.