# Generating continued fractions for square roots of integers

Tags: continued-fractions, project-euler

The problem in Project Euler #64 asks us to generate continued fractions for square roots of integers.
The basic way to do it is:
A fraction
$\frac{\sqrt{n} + b}{d}$ can be expanded to:
$$
1 + \frac{1}{\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}+b}}
$$
$$
1 + \frac{1}{\frac{\sqrt{n}-b}{(\frac{n - b^2}{d})}}
$$

The next step involves factorizing $\frac{\sqrt{n}-b}{(\frac{n-b^2}{d})}$ to
$$
a + \frac{\sqrt{n}+b'}{d'}
$$
where
$$
d' = (\frac{n-b^2}{d}) \\
a = \left \lfloor{\frac{\sqrt{n}-b}{(\frac{n-b^2}{d})}}\right \rfloor \\
b' = -b - ad'
$$

Overall:
$$
1 + \frac{1}{\frac{d}{\sqrt{n}+b}} = 1 + \frac{1}{a + \frac{\sqrt{n}+b'}{d'}}
$$

After this you repeat the steps on $\frac{\sqrt{n}+b'}{d'}$ to get the next fraction.

However in the expression $d' = \frac{n-b^2}{d}$, it is observed that $n-b^2$ is **always evenly divisible** by $d$ (remainder is $0$).
This greatly simplifies the problem. I'm however, stuck at why this property will always hold. I'm hoping you could help me with the proof.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean continu*ed* fractions?

Comment: Lubin came up with a simplified algorithm, I found a way to typeset that by a program. see answers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-11

Comment: @Tanner I edited it. Thanks for the help

Comment: @Jaggy I understand the algorithm and how it proceeds, I was just concerned about the fact that $n-b^2$ is assumed to be divisible by $d$.  I could solve it by induction. Thanks for the help I'll add the solution in answers

Answer (score 1):

Ok I came up with the solution. I'm answering it here in case anybody wants help.
It can be proved using induction
Assume  $n-b^2$ is divisible by $d$.
That is $ \frac{n-b^2}{d}$ is an integer
From $d' = \frac{n-b^2}{d}$ we can say that $ \frac{n-b^2}{d'} = d$ is also an integer

Now we have to prove that in the next step $\frac{n-b'^2}{d'}$ is also an integer

Substituting
$$ b' = -b-ad'$$
in
$$\frac{n-b'^2}{d'}$$
We get
$$
\frac{n-b'^2}{d'} = \frac{n - b^2 - (ad')^2 - 2abd'}{d'}  \\
= \frac{n-b^2}{d'} - \frac{(ad')^2 + 2abd'}{d'}
$$

By our induction hypothesis the first term is an integer $(=d)$ and the other term is divisible by $d'$ trivially.
Hence both of them are integers and thus $\frac{n-b'^2}{d'}$ is also an integer.
The base case of induction is trivial as $d=1$ in the base case.