# An unproven algorithm for generating continued fractions for square roots.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, radicals, continued-fractions, euclidean-algorithm

I found that the following algorithm works correctly for $N=1 \sim 1000$ although I haven't been able to prove it.
If this is already known, please point it out. If not, please prove it.

---

**Algorithm** 
Find the continued fraction expansion of $\sqrt N (N \neq n^2,\ where\ N,n \in \mathbb N)$.

1. Initialization step
   \begin{cases}
   a_0 = \left \lfloor \sqrt N \right \rfloor \\
   b_0 = N-a_0^2 \\
   c_0 = \left \lfloor \frac{2a_0}{b_0} \right \rfloor \\
   \end{cases}
2. Calculation step
   \begin{cases}
   a_t = b_{t-1}\cdot c_{t-1} - a_{t-1} \\
   b_t = \frac{N-a_t^2}{b_{t-1}} \\
   c_t = \left \lfloor \frac{a_0 + a_t}{b_t} \right \rfloor \\
   \end{cases}
3. Judgment step

   If $a_t = a_{t-1}$ or $b_t = b_{t-1}$, output the following value.

   Otherwise, return to step 2.

$$ 
\text{output} = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
[a_0,\overline{\ c_0,\ c_1,\ \cdots,\ c_{t-2},\ c_{t-1},\ c_{t-2},\ \cdots,\ c_1,\ c_0,\ 2a_0}] & (\ a_t = a_{t-1} )\\
[a_0,\overline{\ c_0,\ c_1,\ \cdots,\ c_{t-1},\ c_{t-1},\ \cdots,\ c_1,\ c_0,\ 2a_0}] & (\ b_t = b_{t-1} )
\end{array}
\right.
$$

---

Here are a few examples.

$N=43$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
t & a_t & b_t & c_t \\ \hline
0 & 6 & 7 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 6 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 5 & 3 & 3 \\ \hline
3 & 4 & 9 & 1 \\ \hline
4 & 5 & 2 & 5 \\ \hline
5 & 5 & * & * \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

\begin{array}{ll}
\sqrt{43} &=& [a_0,\overline{\ c_0,\ c_1,\ c_2,\ c_3,\ c_4,\ c_3,\ c_2,\ c_1,\ c_0,\ 2a_0}] \\
&=& [6,\overline{\ 1,\ 1,\ 3,\ 1,\ 5,\ 1,\ 3,\ 1,\ 1,\ 12}]
\end{array}

$N=53$
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline
t & a_t & b_t & c_t \\ \hline
0 & 7 & 4 & 3 \\ \hline
1 & 5 & 7 & 1 \\ \hline
2 & 2 & 7 & * \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

\begin{array}{ll}
\sqrt{53} &=& [a_0,\overline{\ c_0,\ c_1,\ c_1,\ c_0,\ 2a_0}] \\
&=& [7,\overline{\ 3,\ 1,\ 1,\ 3,\ 14}]
\end{array}

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12182701/generating-continued-fractions-for-square-roots) might be a helpful reference for checking existing approaches.

Comment: This looks a lot like the approach in the Niven, Zuckerman, Montgomery textbook.

Comment: Lubin gave a very nice algorithm, something he taught years ago. I've come to think it could be the way Fermat  wrote out such calculations. It uses integer calculations only.. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4