# Write $\sqrt{x}$ as a continued fraction, where $x=((4a^2+1)b+a)^2+4ab+1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, radicals, continued-fractions

I am trying to find an expansion into an arithmetic continued fraction of $\sqrt{x}$, where $x=((4a^2+1)b+a)^2+4ab+1$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$.

So far I have:

Clearly $x < ((4a^2+1)b+a+1)^2$, so the integral part of $\sqrt{x}$, $I = (4a^2 + 1)b + a$, which means $x - I^2 = 4ab + 1$ and $a_1 = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}-I}=\dfrac{\sqrt{x}+I}{x-I}$. Is my work correct so far? and, How might I proceed?

Comment: Here's a hint for you so you don't feel so hopeless: the continued fraction has period $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hard to imagine why you would do this with no actual numbers  For $a=1, b=1$  I get $x=41$

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 41} = 6 +     \frac{  \sqrt {41} - 6 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {41} - 6 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {41} + 6 }{5 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {41} - 4 }{5 } $$
$$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {41} - 4 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {41} + 4 }{5 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {41} - 6 }{5 } $$
$$    \frac{ 5 }{   \sqrt {41} - 6 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {41} + 6 }{1 } = 12 +  \frac{    \sqrt {41} - 6 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 & & 6 & & 2 & & 2 & & 12 & & 2 & & 2 & & 12 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 6 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 13 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 32 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 397 }{ 62 }   & &   \frac{ 826 }{ 129 }   & &   \frac{ 2049 }{ 320 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -5 & & 5 & & -1 & & 5 & & -5 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 41 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  6  \\  
  \frac{ 6 }{ 1 }   & 6^2 - 41 \cdot 1^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 13 }{ 2 }   & 13^2 - 41 \cdot 2^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 32 }{ 5 }   & 32^2 - 41 \cdot 5^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  12  \\  
  \frac{ 397 }{ 62 }   & 397^2 - 41 \cdot 62^2 = 5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 826 }{ 129 }   & 826^2 - 41 \cdot 129^2 = -5 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 2049 }{ 320 }   & 2049^2 - 41 \cdot 320^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  12  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \sqrt { 130} = 11 +     \frac{  \sqrt {130} - 11 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {130} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {130} + 11 }{9 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {130} - 7 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {130} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {130} + 7 }{9 } = 2 +  \frac{    \sqrt {130} - 11 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {130} - 11 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {130} + 11 }{1 } = 22 +  \frac{    \sqrt {130} - 11 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 & & 11 & & 2 & & 2 & & 22 & & 2 & & 2 & & 22 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 11 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 23 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 57 }{ 5 }   & &   \frac{ 1277 }{ 112 }   & &   \frac{ 2611 }{ 229 }   & &   \frac{ 6499 }{ 570 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -9 & & 9 & & -1 & & 9 & & -9 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 130 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  11  \\  
  \frac{ 11 }{ 1 }   & 11^2 - 130 \cdot 1^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 23 }{ 2 }   & 23^2 - 130 \cdot 2^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 57 }{ 5 }   & 57^2 - 130 \cdot 5^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  22  \\  
  \frac{ 1277 }{ 112 }   & 1277^2 - 130 \cdot 112^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 2611 }{ 229 }   & 2611^2 - 130 \cdot 229^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  2  \\  
  \frac{ 6499 }{ 570 }   & 6499^2 - 130 \cdot 570^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  22  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$  \sqrt { 370} = 19 +     \frac{  \sqrt {370} - 19 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {370} - 19 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {370} + 19 }{9 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {370} - 17 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {370} - 17 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {370} + 17 }{9 } = 4 +  \frac{    \sqrt {370} - 19 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {370} - 19 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {370} + 19 }{1 } = 38 +  \frac{    \sqrt {370} - 19 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccc}
 & & 19 & & 4 & & 4 & & 38 & & 4 & & 4 & & 38 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 19 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 77 }{ 4 }   & &   \frac{ 327 }{ 17 }   & &   \frac{ 12503 }{ 650 }   & &   \frac{ 50339 }{ 2617 }   & &   \frac{ 213859 }{ 11118 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -9 & & 9 & & -1 & & 9 & & -9 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 370 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  19  \\  
  \frac{ 19 }{ 1 }   & 19^2 - 370 \cdot 1^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 77 }{ 4 }   & 77^2 - 370 \cdot 4^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 327 }{ 17 }   & 327^2 - 370 \cdot 17^2 = -1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  38  \\  
  \frac{ 12503 }{ 650 }   & 12503^2 - 370 \cdot 650^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 50339 }{ 2617 }   & 50339^2 - 370 \cdot 2617^2 = -9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  4  \\  
  \frac{ 213859 }{ 11118 }   & 213859^2 - 370 \cdot 11118^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  38  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

Comment: The reason is that in that particular form, there is a "nice" periodic expression for the continued fraction: $\sqrt{x} = [(4a^2+1)b+a;\overbrace{2a,2a,(8a^2+2)b+2a},\ldots]$ (I don't know how to write continued fraction, but that's what Sage gives).

Comment: @GarethMa yes. If you look at the ends of my three cf's, you see your "digits"  on the right column. I like to display the digits until the Pell $p^2 - n y^2 = 1$  appears; this takes two of your repeated portion, as for these numbers $n,$   there are solutions to $p^2 - n q^2 = -1$

Comment: I see it now, thanks for the clarification ;) Let's see if OP will be satisfied with "observing pattern from small numbers then proving pattern is correct"

Comment: @GarethMa  one can just manage the proof by concentrating on $ w^2 - n y^2 = -1,$  where the $n$   is his original $x,$  then $w =  16ba^4 + 4a^3 + 8ba^2 + 3a + b, $   and $y= 1 + 4 a^2 .$   Here the fraction $ \frac{w}{y}$  is the third convergent of the c.f. you specify.