# How do I find another generalized Pell equation solution after finding the fundamental solution?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, quadratic-forms, pell-type-equations

If I have a solution $(x_0, y_0)$ to $x^2 - Dy^2 = k$ where D > 1 is not a square, how do I find another solution  $(x_1,y_1)$  to $x^2 - Dy^2 = k$ **without knowing the solution $(u,v)$ to $u^2 - Dv^2 = 1$** ?

I can find the first solution with Conway's topograph quite easily. However, the second solution shows up at the end of the period in the river of Conway's topograph (the river shows up in the topograph of indefinite binary quadratic forms).

I have read multiple answers to similar questions, but the prerequisite for solving the problem is to first find a fundamental solution to $x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$, which I do not have.

**Edit 1:** Forgot to mention that $D$ is too large to try computing the continued fraction. I tried [this code](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/nicf-P_pell.html) implementing the algorithm for this, and it took a long time. Also, $k$ is not necessarily prime, I am looking for a general solution.

---

Here's what I have tried on my own:

I used [this code](https://github.com/Skelpdar/Chakravala/blob/master/chakravala.py) to test out the chakravala method but it was slow.

- I have read [Barbeau's book on the Pell Equation](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/b97610) and started [Buell's book](https://archive.org/details/binaryquadraticf0000buel).
- I read chapters 9-11 of [An Illustrated Theory of Numbers](http://illustratedtheoryofnumbers.com).
- I read [The Sensual (Quadratic) Form](https://bookstore.ams.org/car-26/) but only understood the chapters about the topograph.

Comment: Things are pretty straightforward when $k$   is $\pm$   a prime. If $|k|$ is small enough,  all solutions to $x^2 - Dy^2 = k$  show up in  the continued fraction for $\sqrt D,$  which is also how you solve $x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$   and sometimes   $x^2 - Dy^2 = -1.$

Comment: Well, see what you can do for $x^2 - 5 y^2 =   209 = 11 \cdot 19 .$  The numbers are small enough.......

Comment: It looks like $(\pm 17,4)$ is a fundamental solution to  $^2−5^2=209$. Is there a reason I should look into this?

Comment: Alright;  you've edited.   You should be aware  of methods for Pell  that use only integer arithmetic;  it is necessary  just to find the floor of $\sqrt D;$   this can be done with Newton's method over tyhe integers.

Comment: I am looking into Newton's method! I will update my question with the solution once I have understood this approach.

Comment: alright, you did the example. Note that $9^2 - 5 \cdot 4^2 = 1$    Composing solutions for $1$   and $209$  gives a new solution, $(73, 32)  $   However, there are other  solutions in between. What are those?

Comment: @vvg That gives the same solution or the same solution with a sign changed.

Comment: To get all solutions of Pell equation need only fundamental solutions and fundamental unit of quadratic form of equation.

Comment: @DmitryEzhov Can you do this in polynomial time?

Comment: @WillJagy Is there a resource you recommend for Newton's method? I may have not tried or attempted to use that method correctly.

Comment: @WillJagy Also, it appears that $( \pm 23, 8)$ is another solution to $x^2−5y^2=209$.

Comment: @ender if you use Theorem 3.3 in the first file I linked to in my answer below (not the Lenstra article) and use $u = 9+4\sqrt{5}$ there, it tells you each $x+y\sqrt{5}$ such that $x^2 - 5y^2 = 209$ is a power of $u$ times a solution where $|x| \leq 32$ and $|y| \leq 12$.  So just take $y = 0, 1, \ldots, 12$ to see when $209+5y^2$ is a perfect square and you'll see that it happens only when $y$ is $4$ or $8$: those are the solutions you already found.  So the solutions are $(x+y\sqrt{5})u^k$ where $(x,y)$ is $(\pm 17, \pm 4)$ or $(\pm 23, \pm 8)$ (independent choices of signs).

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to find more integral solutions *without* ever using information about integral solutions to the equation $x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$?

The main structure theorem about integral solutions to $x^2 - Dy^2 = k$ is threefold:

(i) when $(x_0,y_0)$ is an integral solution to $x^2 - Dy^2 = k$, so are the coefficients of $(x_0 + y_0\sqrt{D})(a+b\sqrt{D})$ where $(a,b)$ is an arbitrary solution to $x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$,

(ii) there are finitely many integral solutions $(x_0,y_0),\ldots,(x_m,y_m)$ to $x^2 - Dy^2 = k$ such that *every other* integral solution to this equation occurs as coefficients of $(x_i+y_i\sqrt{D})(a+b\sqrt{D})$ for some $i = 1,\ldots,m$ and $a^2 - Db^2 = 1$,

(iii) in terms of *one* $(a,b)$ where $a^2 - Db^2 = 1$ and $a, b \geq 1$, you can find the finitely many solutions $(x_i,y_i)$ for (ii) in an explicit box in the plane.

See Theorem 3.3 and Corollary 3.5 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/ugradnumthy/pelleqn2.pdf). Section 4 there has several worked examples.

You say in your answer that "$D$ is too large to try computing the continued fraction" of $\sqrt{D}$.  What kind of $D$ are you using?  If you find enough integral solutions to $x^2 - Dy^2 = k$, then taking a *suitable* ratio $(x+y\sqrt{D})/(x'+y'\sqrt{D})$ for some of them is going to give you a solution to $x^2 - Dy^2 = 1$, so bypassing the direct use of solutions to the Pell equation in solving he generalized Pell equation is going to amount to solving the Pell equation by another method. So maybe you should look at a survey paper on ways to solve Pell equations, like Lenstra's AMS Notices article https://www.ams.org/notices/200202/fea-lenstra.pdf.

Comment: I want to find more integral solutions without ever using information about integral solutions to the equation  $x^2−Dy^2=1$ because $D$ is large.

I will read [this article](https://www.ams.org/notices/200202/fea-lenstra.pdf).

Comment: And how large is "large" for you?

Comment: K, his original example is $x^2  - 91 y^2  = -10.$   With $1574^2 - 91 165^2 = 1,....$

Comment: 617 decimal digit/2048 bit numbers are large.

Answer (score 1):

All solutions of equation $a^2-91b^2=-10$ derives from modulo polynomial $a+bx\equiv(-x\pm9)(-1574-165x)^j\pmod{x^2-91}$ where $j=$`0,1,2,...`.

[pari/gp](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html) code:

```
{
  D= 91; C= -10;
  Q= bnfinit('x^2-D,1);
  fu= Q.fu[1]; print("Fundamental Unit: "fu);
  N= bnfisintnorm(Q, C); print("Fundamental Solutions (Norm): "N);
  for(k=1, #N, n= N[k];
   print("\n\nNorm: "n"\n");
   for(j=0, 8,
    s= lift(n*fu^j);
    X= abs(polcoeff(s, 0)); Y= abs(polcoeff(s, 1));  
    if(X^2-D*Y^2==C, if(Y, if(X==floor(X), if(Y==floor(Y),
     y= Y; x= X; 
     print("("x", "y")    j = "j);
    ))))
   )
  )
};
```

Output:

```
Fundamental Unit: Mod(-165*x - 1574, x^2 - 91)
Fundamental Solutions (Norm): [-x + 9, -x - 9]


Norm: -x + 9

(9, 1)    j = 0
(849, 89)    j = 1
(2672661, 280171)    j = 2
(8413535979, 881978219)    j = 3
(26485808589231, 2776467153241)    j = 4
(83377317025363209, 8740317716424449)    j = 5
(262471767510034792701, 27514517394837012211)    j = 6
(826261040744272502059539, 86615692018629198015779)    j = 7
(2601069493791202326448636071, 272666170960127320516660081)    j = 8


Norm: -x - 9

(9, 1)    j = 0
(29181, 3059)    j = 1
(91861779, 9629731)    j = 2
(289180851111, 30314390129)    j = 3
(910341227435649, 95429690496361)    j = 4
(2865753894786571941, 300412635368154299)    j = 5
(9021392350446901034619, 945698880709259236891)    j = 6
(28399340253452949670408671, 2977059776060112709578569)    j = 7
(89401114096477535115545461689, 9371783229338354100494098321)    j = 8
```

Comment: My issue with computing the continued fraction for large D was speed. bnfinit runs in sub-exponential time if I am correct. I am looking for a polynomial time algorithm.

Comment: Currently is no polynomial time algorithm, otherwise the factorization problem and RSA would have already been breacked.

Answer (score 1):

here is  a method for standard Pell

Method described  by Prof. Lubin  at [Continued fraction of $\sqrt{67} - 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction-of-sqrt67-4/2216011#2216011)

$$  \sqrt { 91} = 9 +     \frac{  \sqrt {91} - 9 }{ 1 }  $$
$$    \frac{ 1 }{   \sqrt {91} - 9 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 9 }{10 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 1 }{10 } $$
$$    \frac{ 10 }{   \sqrt {91} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 1 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 8 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {91} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 8 }{3 } = 5 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 7 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {91} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 7 }{14 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 7 }{14 } $$
$$    \frac{ 14 }{   \sqrt {91} - 7 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 7 }{3 } = 5 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 8 }{3 } $$
$$    \frac{ 3 }{   \sqrt {91} - 8 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 8 }{9 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 1 }{9 } $$
$$    \frac{ 9 }{   \sqrt {91} - 1 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 1 }{10 } = 1 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 9 }{10 } $$
$$    \frac{ 10 }{   \sqrt {91} - 9 }  =  \frac{    \sqrt {91} + 9 }{1 } = 18 +  \frac{    \sqrt {91} - 9 }{1 } $$

Simple continued fraction tableau:
$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccccccccccccccccccccc}
 & & 9 & & 1 & & 1 & & 5 & & 1 & & 5 & & 1 & & 1 & & 18 & \\ 
 \\ 
  \frac{ 0 }{ 1 }   &   \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & &   \frac{ 9 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 10 }{ 1 }   & &   \frac{ 19 }{ 2 }   & &   \frac{ 105 }{ 11 }   & &   \frac{ 124 }{ 13 }   & &   \frac{ 725 }{ 76 }   & &   \frac{ 849 }{ 89 }   & &   \frac{ 1574 }{ 165 }    \\ 
  \\ 
 & 1 & & -10 & & 9 & & -3 & & 14 & & -3 & & 9 & & -10 & & 1
 \end{array}
 $$

$$ 
 \begin{array}{cccc}
  \frac{ 1 }{ 0 }   & 1^2 - 91 \cdot 0^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  9  \\  
  \frac{ 9 }{ 1 }   & 9^2 - 91 \cdot 1^2 = -10 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 10 }{ 1 }   & 10^2 - 91 \cdot 1^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 19 }{ 2 }   & 19^2 - 91 \cdot 2^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 105 }{ 11 }   & 105^2 - 91 \cdot 11^2 = 14 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 124 }{ 13 }   & 124^2 - 91 \cdot 13^2 = -3 &     \mbox{digit}  &  5  \\  
  \frac{ 725 }{ 76 }   & 725^2 - 91 \cdot 76^2 = 9 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 849 }{ 89 }   & 849^2 - 91 \cdot 89^2 = -10 &     \mbox{digit}  &  1  \\  
  \frac{ 1574 }{ 165 }   & 1574^2 - 91 \cdot 165^2 = 1 &     \mbox{digit}  &  18  \\  
 \end{array}
 $$

Putting the $(x_n, y_n)$  pairs that solve $x_n^2 - 91 y_n^2 = -10$  in  increasing order, we get recurrences
$$ x_{n+4} = 3148 x_{n+2}  - x_n,$$

$$ y_{n+4} = 3148 y_{n+2}  - y_n.$$

The pairs   are
$$  (-849, 89)  $$
$$  (-9, 1)  $$
$$  (  9, 1)  $$
$$  (849, 89)  $$
$$  (29181, 3059)  $$
$$ (2672661,       280171) $$