Reference request: Pell's equation and the fundamental unit of real quadratic number fields
Let $d > 0$ be a squarefree integer and $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt d)$. Dirichlet's Unit Theorem asserts that
$$\mathcal O_K^* \cong \mathbb Z \times \{\pm 1 \}.$$
A generator of the free part of $\mathcal O_K^*$ (called a fundamental unit of $\mathcal O_K$) can be found by finding the smallest  solution to Pell's equations
$$x^2 - d y^2 = \pm 1$$
in positive integers, at least if $d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$. If $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we have to look at the equations
$$x^2 - dy^2 = \pm 4$$
instead.
These Pell-type equations can be solved by using continued fractions.
I am looking for a reference that provides a complete treatment of the relationship between the above Pell-type equations, fundamental units, and continued fractions. Not every fact about continued fractions needs to be proved in the reference; there are plenty of good references here.
However, the reference should contain the theory for $d \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ as well, not only the cases $d \equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$; the image in this question seems to be what I'm looking for, however, the question is pretty old and I cannot find the reference by googling.

Try some good intro Number Theory book, like Hardy and Wright, or Niven, Zuckerman and Montgomery, or LeVeque.

@GerryMyerson Thanks. However, I am unable to find a complete treatment of $x^2 - dy^2 = \pm 4$ in there (at least not in Hardy-Wright, Niven-Zuckerman-Montgomery, and LeVeque Vol II; I don't have access to LeVeque, Vol I right now).

or this and this

I like Buell, Binary Quadratic Forms.

take a look at http://zakuski.math.utsa.edu/~jagy/BLOG_2014_July_15.pdf   and see simple Pell method at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2215918/continued-fraction

@J.W.Tanner there is no systematic use of continued fractions at the links you cite in order to show Pell-type equations have a nontrivial solution.
