# Find the fundamental solution of $x^2 - 95y^2 = 1$ and of $x^2 - 74y^2 = 1$.

Tags: number-theory

I'm trying to practice finding the fundamental solution of Pell Equations, but have not found efficient ways of finding fundamental solutions. However, it seems that using [continued fractions](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Yang.pdf) would provide an effective way of finding these solutions, according to the link. To better understand how to actually use continued fractions through examples (with numbers),

> How would you find the fundamental solution of $x^2 - 95y^2 = 1$ and of $x^2 - 74y^2 = 1$ using continued fractions?

Comment: You only need the convergents corresponging to the continued fractions of $\sqrt{95}$ and $\sqrt{74}$ and determine the first satisfying the Pell-equation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the current question asks for an explicit computation and so is not a duplicate. I'd like to see it reopened. The answers in that question are not directly usable here.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the continued fraction for $\sqrt{95},$ for example?

Comment: Take the period of the continued fraction of $\sqrt{n}$, let's call it $h$. Then, compute $c_{h-1}$ where $c_m:=p_m/q_m$ denotes the $m^{th}$ partial convergent. The pair $(p_{h-1},q_{h-1})$ is your fundamental solution. If you follow this method correctly; you should get $(39,4)$ and $(3699, 430)$ as the fundamental solutions to your questions.

Comment: A very good explanation, and a step-by-step example, can be found in section 6.2.2 of http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/cfINTRO.html#section6.1

Comment: @lhf I added an answer for 29, 95, 74 at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045127/how-to-find-a-fundamental-solution-to-pells-equation/2811551#2811551

Comment: @saulspatz I added an answer including 95, 74 at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045127/how-to-find-a-fundamental-solution-to-pells-equation/2811551#2811551   where I had previously used a very general method.

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you (+1).