# Find all positive integers $n$ for which $\prod_{k=1}^n\left(k^4+\frac14\right)$ is the square of a rational number

Tags: products

**Question**
Find all positive integers $n$ for which$$N=\left({1^4+\frac14}\right)\left({2^4+\frac14}\right)...\left({n^4+\frac14}\right)$$ is the square of a rational number.

**My attempt**
$$N=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(k^4+\frac14\right)$$
we have :
$$k^4+\frac{1}{4}=k^4+\frac{1}{4}+k^2-k^2=\left({k^2+\frac{1}{2}}\right)^2-k^2=\left({k^2+k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left({k^2-k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)$$

therefore:
$$\begin{align}N&=\prod_{k=1}^n\left({k^4+\frac{1}{4}}\right)\\&=\prod_{k=1}^n\left({k^2+k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left({k^2-k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)\\&=\prod_{k=1}^n\left({k^2+k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)\prod_{k=1}^n\left({k^2-k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left({n^2+n+\frac{1}{2}}\right)\left({\prod_{k=1}^n\left({k^2+k+\frac{1}{2}}\right)}\right)^2
\end{align}$$

Now we can see that the equality :
$$\frac{1}{2}\left({n^2+n+\frac{1}{2}}\right)=m^2$$
where $m\in \mathbb{R}$
**I stopped at the solution here. I appreciate everyone's interest. Is there an idea on how to complete the solution?**

Comment: $$8m^2=\cdots=(2n+1)^2+1$$ See https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PellEquation.html OR https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045127/how-to-find-a-fundamental-solution-to-pells-equation

Comment: Extending the comment of @labbhattacharjee, set $~X = (2n+1), Y = 2m.~$  Then, you are looking for all integer solutions to $~X^2 - 2Y^2 = -1.~$  In the theory of **continued fractions**, with $~X,Y~$ further constrained to each be a positive integer, the infinite set of all satisyfing ordered pairs $~(X = P_k, Y = Q_k) ~$ is defined by $$P_k + Q_k\sqrt{2} = \left[ ~1 + \sqrt{2} ~\right]^k ~: k,P_k,Q_k \in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~k ~\text{odd}.$$

Comment: Re last comment, see also [Khinchin pdf](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf), chapter 1 (specifically) and see also [Old's pdf](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf).  See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749487/algebra-direct-connect-pell-eqn-soln-p-nk-q-nk-with-p-n-q-n-sqrtd/2752161?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C23.4532#2752161).

Comment: Please answer in tge answer, not in comments, or not at all. Note my attempt to obey this rule resulted in a drive-by downvote, which then led to deletion.

Comment: Based on the first few successful cases (found via Mathematica) I'd suggest that the relevant OEIS equence is [https://oeis.org/A001652](A001652). This is supported by the following entry on said OEIS entry: "Numbers m such that Product_{k=1..m} (4*k^4+1) is a square (see A274307)" .

Comment: @labbhattacharjee  for integers, congruences say $(2n+1)^2 + 1 $  is never a multiple of $8$  as $(2n+1)^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8$