# Generating digits of sqrt of 2

Tags: numerical-methods

If I wanted to generate a billion digits of sqrt of 2, what is the quickest way of doing that? (I am talking about the mathematical methods  and the programming issue, not hardware memory limit problem)

Today I coded a program in php, using bisection method from numerical analysis. But a float in php can only display max 13 digits.

Questions:

1. What is the most effective mathematical method for doing that? One from numerical analysis or adding values of a series?
2. What is the best programming tool for that in php say, considering the limit of 13 of digits of a float variable?

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Question 1. asks for mathematical methods, question 2. asks for programming tools.

Comment: [here](https://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/sqrt2.1mil) you have 1 million digits but they do not indicate the method. I guess it is a rapidly converging series.

Comment: Bisection is very slow because each loop only gives you 1 more bit. You can do *much* better than that. Eg, the [Babylonian method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) aka Heron's formula (which is a special case of Newton's method) doubles the precision on each loop.

Comment: In English is this area of mathematics called arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

Comment: Why PHP? In Python, it would be easier because arbitrary precision integer arithmetic is built into Python. There's also the standard `decimal` module for arbitrary precision fixed-point decimal arithmetic.  However, doing calculations with a billion decimal digits tends to be slow &/or difficult unless you have a lot of RAM.

Comment: "Most effective" depends on what is available at what cost.  For example, whether to do your intermediate arithmetics as rationals with large integer denominators and numerators (e.g., directly computing continued fractions of $\sqrt{2}$ until denominator is large enough), or as floats with large significand.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/694814) can be found series that are all based on the series expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ but whose convergence can be improved by the use of the first convergents of $\sqrt{2}$ (resulting from its continued fraction expansion).

Comment: Here's some [live Python code using the Heron algorithm](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtTkFqwzAQvOsVQ3KRHOHIChRaCITeC6UfKCaxXWHLsmQd8vyu1j2EtoLVanZmNbPHqxuwxpSlVTXe32A_3DzAGtvU5rk2T6JPwcO3-QvOLyFl9FMISWMKQ2OEuLg5d6m9ZnHrenxKIpf1fFIvAnQWjYgzGo2GcR8SHNyM1M5Dt4l_pA_yBRXVAZZ6LKX5WcZRsHgkFeeQheAokmmlNt9EseSosbt1V-fbad1thC9pDKoKI-M7Yelpc_M6HtnYsxuBqMpt_8t-17R8wOkxPrs69XtAv_0Zqm_xo12U&lang=python) that can easily calculate >100,000 digits of sqrt(2) in a couple of seconds. For larger sizes, most of the time is consumed in converting from binary to decimal & printing.