# Are Groups and Rings Closed to Infinite Addition/Multiplication Operations?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I found that the rings in real analysis are closed for finite union operations,but not closed for countable infinite union operations (only $\sigma$-rings are closed).This reminds me for group and ring structures in algebra,is them closed for infinite additions or multiplications ?

Comment: 'infinite addition' and 'infinite multiplication' are not defined on general group and ring structures. There can be structures that these operations are well defined, maybe something like topological groups.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessarily the case. Consider the field $\mathbb{Q}$ (which constitutes a ring, and also a group under addition). We have the result that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

The left-hand side is an infinite sum of rationals, but the right-hand side is clearly irrational, and hence we do not have closure under infinite addition.

> *Edit:* I suppose it might not be as obvious as it appears at first glance that $\pi^2$ is irrational (though one sees a proof [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pi_Squared_is_Irrational)). Another argument comes in from, if one prefers, [Leibniz' formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80):
> $$
> \pi = 4 \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
> $$

One can do this for multiplication as well, with the equivalent result

$$\prod_{\text{$p$ prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-2}} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

Here, again, we have an infinite product of rationals on the left-hand side, but an irrational on the right hand side.

> *Edit:* If likewise unconvinced on the matter of $\pi^2$, then one may use the [Wallis product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product):
> $$
> \pi = 2 \prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4n^2}{4n^2-1}
> $$

Comment: Irrationallity of $\pi^2$ is not really clear, since irrational number can have rational square, for instance $\sqrt{2}$. It requires proof. One may look for https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Pi_Squared_is_Irrational Also, there are rational series expansion for $\sqrt{2}$, using binomial series. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694699/infinite-series-for-sqrt-2

Comment: Similarly $e=\sum_{n\geq 0} 1/n!$.

Comment: A much simpler example is $\sum_1^{\infty}1$. This shows that the rationals, the reals, the complex numbers are not closed under "infinite addition".

Comment: This also assumes that "infinite addition" has to mean the typical definition by convergence of partial sums.